# How to override the default image loaded by a facet of orderingList richfaces component

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, richfaces

I'm trying to change the image loaded by default in the facets of orderingList richfaces component.
The default image is being loaded from DATB folder so i'm trying to override the loading and make from a local folder in my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00jeh.png)

So, i'm trying to override the image used for first button and use mine instead.

For example, the generated img tag for topControlDisabled facet is :

```
<img style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px;" width="15" height="15"
     border="0" alt="topControlDisabled" src="/XXXX/faces/a4j_3_1_6.SR1org.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.OrderingListIconTopDisabled/DATB/eAE7Pynr9d75nz59BgAgIgbq">
```

How i can override the src attribute to make the facet use my image link ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the controls, e.g.

```
<rich:orderingList … >
    <f:facet name="topControl">
        <!-- your code here -->
    </f:facet>
    …
```

This will replace the "First" button, the other facet names are `upControl`, `downControl` and `bottomControl`. See the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#d0e38485).

Comment: yeah, thanks, I've tried that and it's working, it's loading now my own image instead of the default one for every facet.